# ElevateZoom, show zoomed section on different div which is always on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the [ElevateZoom](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/) plugin in my web app. But the default behavior of the plugin is that the zoom section is shown only when the mouse hovers around the particular area.

What I am trying to achieve is, show the zoomed version of the image in a different DIV and will keep on showing the zoomed pic even after the mouse is removed from the pic.

Is `ElevateZoom` plugin able to do so by default , or has someone already achieved this functionality with the plugin.If so, any pointers or help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elevateZoom plugin can’t do this out of the box.

If you look at the plugin code (jquery.elevatezoom.js) you can see the `mouseleave` function on line #450 and if you are ok with editing the plugin code you can just replace `self.setElements("hide")` with `self.setElements("")`. But I don’t think this will give the desired result.

You can either find another plugin or hack your way through this one. For the latter it's good to know that you can access the elevateZoom object this way:

```
var $image = $('#your-image').elevateZoom({...});
console.log( $image.data('elevateZoom') );
```